# MySQL and phpMyAdmin - copy data from one database to another?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Here is the MySQL code I have tried:

```
"INSERT INTO wpcustom_productmeta.wpc_productmeta(brand,model,country,carrier) 
VALUES (SELECT meta_value FROM wordpress.wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='brand'),
        (SELECT meta_value FROM wordpress.wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='model'),
        (SELECT meta_value FROM wordpress.wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='country'),
        (SELECT meta_value FROM wordpress.wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='carrier')";
```

I would like to insert data into `wpcustom_productmeta.wpc_productmeta` from the separate database and table `wordpress.wp_postmeta` but I want to choose only specific columns.

Here is the structure of both tables:[image: wp_postmeta] [image: wpc_productmeta]

Comment: "I think the code says more than thousand words" - not when its written in a language you have invented yourself (if it were written in SQL it would work).

Comment: yes please help me put it right

Comment: could you post your both tables structure?

Comment: I added some screenshots to show the table structure.

Comment: did you try my query? my query is ok to get result you asked for. But I thinbk you've missed one column in your `wpc_productmeta` table. it must have `product_id` or `post_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still not clear to me.

But you can try to start from (I guess that you have `product_id` column in both tables):

```
INSERT INTO wpcustom_productmeta.wpc_productmeta(product_id,brand,model,country,carrier) 
SELECT 
  product_id,
  MAX(IF(meta_key='brand',meta_value,''),
  MAX(IF(meta_key='model',meta_value,''),
  MAX(IF(meta_key='country',meta_value,''),
  MAX(IF(meta_key='carrier',meta_value,''),
FROM wordpress.wp_postmeta
GROUP BY product_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use self-joins of the `wp_postmeta` table to get all the rows related to a particular post. Then use the results of this entire `SELECT` as the data to insert.

```
INSERT INTO wpcustom_productmeta.wpc_productmeta (brand, model, country, carrier)
SELECT DISTINCT m1.meta_value, m2.meta_value, m3.meta_value, m4.meta_value, 
FROM wordpress.wp_postmeta AS m1
JOIN wordpress.wp_postmeta AS m2 ON m1.post_id = m2.post_id
JOIN wordpress.wp_postmeta AS m3 ON m1.post_id = m3.post_id
JOIN wordpress.wp_postmeta AS m4 ON m1.post_id = m4.post_id
WHERE m1.meta_key = 'brand'
  AND m2.meta_key = 'model'
  AND m3.meta_key = 'country'
  AND m4.meta_key = 'carrier'
```

Comment: I get error: subquery returns more than 1 row, just as you said it doesn't work in this case. do you have a better idea to do what I intend?

Comment: Is there some key column that can be used to join all the different subqueries to get all the corresponding rows?

Comment: It would probably be obvious if I knew WordPress, but I don't.

Comment: maybe the screenshots help?